# Android App force closes when using Push notification from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm facing few problems since I started using Parse Push for android.
1. I'm unable to send notifications when the app is not running in the background.
2. The app force closes when it's not running in the background and I send a push notification.
3. The app force closes when I click on the push received.

Android Manifest

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="cn.loptest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Main Activity onCreate code

```
Parse.initialize(this, "********", "*******");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

If I use `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback` with the above code I always get a "Connot Resolve Method"

TIA

Comment: Firstly. It's not a good idea for you to post your app key and secret in a public forum. Secondly. Please post stack trace from crashes.

Comment: @IvanWooll it wasn't my app key. I have removed many characters from it. Stack trace will be up soon. I reverted back to stable code so as to move on with other features.

Comment: provide your code where you check that app is in background or foreground @NavneethT

Comment: @Aashvi the problem is I'm using a tutorial to implement the push through Parse, and it doesn't have a code that searches if the app is foreground or background. As for now, if the app in the background, then push is successful. If the app is not running in either states and I try to send a push, I get a force close message.